# How to convert mysql query to sequelize?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

### Test table

```
p_id   p_type   name
----------------------------------
100    Y        hong
101    Y        kim
200    N        park
201    N        John
```

I want to insert "102  Y   choi" into Test table.

**mysql query**

```
insert into test(p_id,p_type,name) 
select (max(p_id)+1),'Y','choi' from test where p_type='Y'
```

What is the equivalent query in sequelize?

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any other option but to make two queries in a transaction:

```
sequelize.transaction(t => {
  Test.findAll({
    order: [['p_id', 'DESC']],
    where: { p_type: 'Y' },
    limit: 1
  }, {transaction: t}).then(maxTest=>{
    const max = (maxTest[0] || {p_id: 0}).p_id + 1;
    return Test.create({
        p_id: max,
        p_type: 'Y',
        name: 'choi'
    }, {transaction: t})
  })
})
```

Comment: But, According to your method, `202 'Y' 'choi'` is inserted into the table.
What I want is to insert `102 'Y' 'choi'` into the table by adding **1** to the maximum **p_id** of the records with t_type = 'Y'.

Please, Help me~

Comment: @hong.s.k then I dont see any other way but to use a transaction. Updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: tell me how it went !